# How to see the surface arc in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, platformer, world-editor

How to see the surface arc in Unity?

There is the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydG8kUrtCB4) and in this tutorial we can see the arc in editor:

[image]

While I can not see it. I checked that all my gizmos are enabled.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I enable the arc?

Comment: Try toggling the `Use One Way` option, mine was showing/ disabling the effector arc on switching it

Comment: @Zibelas, thanks. But it does not work for me.